# do functions in sql server have different permissions rules?

Tags: sql-server

Here's the situation. I'm writing an automated test that walks the list of dependencies for a proc and determines if an acct has rights for all of the dependent objects.

My code looks like this:

```
exec sp_depends 'the_proc_name'

-- run this query on the results of sp_depends: 

select
case                          
when exists (                                   
select *
from sys.database_permissions dp
where grantee_principal_id=USER_ID('TheAccount')                                     
    and major_id=object_id('dbo.theDependentObject')                                     
    and minor_id=0
    and state_desc = 'GRANT')
then 'true'
else 'false'                                
end;
```

It all seems to be working fine, but there's a **hiccup when it encounters a function**. I have one case where `TheAccount` doesn't have rights to a function (the query above returns false). However the proc that calls the function in question runs fine when running under `TheAccount`. So there's either something wrong with my test code or functions have special permission behavior in SQL-Server that I'm not aware of.

Should I change the code to only search for 'DENY' instead of 'GRANT'? Do functions that are called in procs inherit the permissions of the calling proc except when the execute rights are explicitly denied? Does my code suck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running static SQL from a stored proc, the stored proc runs with the authority of the id that last created/modified the stored proc; not the id of the person running the stored proc.

For example, this is the same ability that allows you to use a stored proc to run an Insert statement without giving the person running the stored proc Insert Authority on the underlying table.

One note - this does not apply when you are using dynamic SQL (with the exec statement).  In that case, the person running the stored proc, must have the necessary authority for that SQL statement.

So I'm not sure if your unit tests will provide you what you are looking for since the rights to dependent objects are taken care of, to some extent, by the way SQL Server handles Stored Proc security.

Comment: What? If I create a proc and don't grant execute permissions to you you won't be able to execute it unless you are dbo  GRANT EXECUTE ON ProcNAme to UserName...try it out create a proc and then try executing as a user with read access only. Of course you can use EXECUTE AS  in the proc but that is another story

Comment: So if a DBA modifies a stored proc, then a datareader user runs the proc, the proc will be run with the authority of the DBA. That's what you're saying, if I'm reading it right. That sounds patently false.

Comment: Yes, the stored proc will be run with the authority of the DBA.  But only the static SQL contained in the stored proc.  And only if you give the person EXEC rights on the stored proc.  

This allows you to create a Stored Proc that does an insert without requiring you give insert authority to everyone; instead you can give out Exec on the stored proc.  Here's a link to an example, http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/security_sp_p1.aspx.  This example is for SQL Server 2000 but it applies to 2005 & 2008 as well.